# Accounts Receivable & Payable - should payed ones be there or not?

Tags: accounting

I am working on accounting application and have one dilemma on how to treat Account Payable & Receivable with respect to them actualy been or not payed.

For example, Company A sells Product B to Customer X. They issue an invoice, send to Customer X and at that point of time, the transaction is shown on Account Receivable with notion its for Customer X and other info (date, etc...).

The question is, what happens when Customer X actually pays for it? Should that transaction still be visible in Account Receivable or removed from it?

I am interested in it from accounting point of view.

Comment: You are talking core accounting ! you cannot be not interested in Accounting point of view.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is for programming related questions, not tutorials in how to do accounting.

Comment: @Ken, description for this tag says 'Systematic recording, reporting, and analysis of financial transactions of a business.'. So i must say i really dont see a problem.

Comment: The problem is that you're not asking about a programming related topic, which is the primary requirement that must be met. Other tags are irrelevant without having met that first requirement. You can also find a tag for `windows`, but asking how to use Windows Explorer to copy files is off-topic here with or without that tag. There are also tags here for things like `computer`.

Comment: Ok, can you please give some reference where you got conclusion that tag Accounting must contain exclusively programming topic? I havent found any such reference so can you please provide one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a payment is applied on this invoice, Accounts Receivable should be credited and its balance for this customer should be 0